# Align a fixed positioned element to center horizontally

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have three components - a logo, `#menuA` and menuB. I would like the logo centrally aligned, menuA in the top left and menuB in the top right.

The parent container `#nav` has `position:fixed` which appears to be causing me problems. I can get the logo roughly in the middle but it appears to be slightly to the right - I think because menuA is wider than menuB.

This is what I have so far: **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6q8m9rfj/)**

```css
#nav {
  position:fixed;
  height:30px;
  background:#FFF;
  padding:10px 20px;
  z-index:1;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
}

#logo {
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  right:50%;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size:28px;
  color:#333333;
}

#menuA {
  float:left;
}

#menuB {
  float:right;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="nav">
  <div id="logo">Logo</div>

  <div class="ui basic buttons" id="menuA">
    <a ui-sref="editor"><div class="ui button" style="padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;"><i class="file outline icon" style="margin-right:0px;"></i>New</div></a>
    <div class="ui button" style="padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;" ng-click="save()"><i class="add icon" style="margin-right:0px;"></i>Save</div>
    <div class="ui button" style="padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;" ng-click="fork()"><i class="fork code icon" style="margin-right:0px;"></i>Fork</div>
  </div>

  <div class="ui selection dropdown" id="menuB">
    <input type="hidden" name="gender">
    <div class="default text">Language</div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item" data-value="0">Javascript</div>
      <div class="item" data-value="1">HTML</div>
      <div class="item" data-value="2">CSS</div>
      <div class="item" data-value="3">Python</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="clear"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please mind posting the HTML as well, also providing an online demo on jsfiddle would be great.

Comment: Sorry - just added HTML to my question

Comment: Just added a Fiddle too - I think the logo is being positioned using the left most point so it's being pushed to the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xvjwr8ed/1/)**

If you give `width` (i.e 100px) to your logo, then it will solve your problem.

**CSS**

```
#nav {
  position:fixed;
  height:30px;
  background:#FFF;
  padding:10px 20px;
  z-index:1;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
}

#logo {
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size:28px;
  color:#333333;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

#menuA {
  float:left;
}

#menuB {
  float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `fixed` positioned logo doesn't have an explicit `width` you could that horizontally by using [CSS Transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#translateX) as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/voweve/1/edit)**

```css
#logo {
  position:fixed;
  /* other declarations */

  left:50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

It's worth noting that transforms [are supported in **IE9+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility).

By any chance if you could specify an explicit `width` to the element, you can use a negative margin (equal to the half of the width) to achieve the same result.

```css
#logo {
  position:fixed;
  /* other declarations */
  width: 100px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: -50px; /* = 100px / 2 */
}
```

Comment: kinda hoping for a simple fix ha ha

Comment: @tommyd456 Here is the demo of the second approach: http://jsbin.com/voweve/5/edit

Comment: @tommyd456 BTW Second approach is my :)

Comment: @tommyd456 Make sure that the text inside `#logo` is also aligned to center by `text-align: center;`.

Comment: @tommyd456 Since 11 is grater than 5*2 min. I think so :) Anyway it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @HashemQolami I think reputation really matter.

Comment: I've given the tick to Mary as I think she offered the complete solution first (just)

Comment: @MaryMelody The funniest thing is if you subtract 10 from 16 (time difference between our answers) it remains 6 minuets which means I wan't even able to edit my post to duplicate your solution. Anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `left:50%;`

```
#logo {
  position:fixed;

  right:50%;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size:28px;
  color:#333333;
}
```

Comment: @tommyd456 So it would be again a little bit to left.

Comment: yeah I noticed that and withdrew my comments. Thanks anyway Jake